# How do I use Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground for Document List API?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm having an issue playing with the Document List API on the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground). All the other APIs work except for this one. The request is being sent from the playground as:

```
GET /feeds/default/private/full/ HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: OAuth <the oAuth string generated>
```

And the response is coming back as:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
status: 400
content-length: 19
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
expires: Tue, 29 May 2012 17:11:47 GMT
x-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
server: GSE
via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
cache-control: private, max-age=0
date: Tue, 29 May 2012 17:11:47 GMT
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-content-encoding: gzip

Invalid request URI
```

Is the API simply deprecated because of Google Drive or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send requests to version 3 of the API, by either adding the `?v=3` query parameter to the URI or sending the `GData-Version: 3.0` header.