# OAuth 2.0 Playground List spreadsheet metadata: Invalid request URI

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am testing Google Spreadsheet 3.0 API and playing with [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=4/mOswS7Ibshq6uet0KPw177H0o4Ug.IquE6H5wQdYXOl05ti8ZT3ZZGysqdgI).
When trying to use List spreadsheet metadata request, I am getting the error **Invalid request URI**. Here are the Response details:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 19
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
-content-encoding: gzip
Server: GSE
Reason: Bad Request
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
X-chromium-appcache-fallback-override: disallow-fallback
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Sun, 18 Nov 2012 19:56:29 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Sun, 18 Nov 2012 19:56:29 GMT
Invalid request URI
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803812/how-do-i-use-googles-oauth-2-0-playground-for-document-list-api), but without success.

I will appreciate if anyone can point to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have found the solution to my own question. 
It looks like a bug in OAuth 2.0 Playground: when you select from "List possible operations", List metadata menu item returns the following Request URL: http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/default/private/full sending this request return above error. You have to use http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full Request URL instead, it seems to be working.